# Regional Opsworks stack can't be found by Cloudformation

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, stack, aws-cloudformation, aws-opsworks

I have a `Cloudformation` template that modifies an `Opsworks` stack by adding few resources.

The `Opsworks stack` is deployed in the region `eu-west-1` which is the `API endpoint region` as well and it shows on the side of the name of the stack: `Regional`.

When I run the `Cloudformation template` ( I give the stack ID as a parameter) I get this error:

`Unable to find stack with ID xxxxxxx`

I guess Cloudformation can only see the opsworks resources which are in us-east-1 region?

I tried changing the region of Cloudformation and deploy the template but the stack is still unfound.

How can I let `Cloudformation` search for the stack in all regions?

Should I clone the opsworks stack and change the endpoint to us-east-1 region?

What would be the best solution?

**Template**

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Description": "Add a  layer to an existing stack",
  "Mappings": {
    "Region2Principal": {
      "eu-west-1": {
        "EC2Principal": "ec2.amazonaws.com",
        "OpsWorksPrincipal": "opsworks.amazonaws.com"
      }
    },
  },
  "Parameters": {
    "Environment" : {
      "Description": "The Environnement variable ",
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "dev",
      "AllowedValues" : ["test", "prod"]
    },
    "InstanceType": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "m4.large",
      "AllowedValues" : ["t2.micro", "m1.small", "m1.large","m4.large","m4.xlarge","m4.2xlarge","m4.4xlarge","m4.10xlarge","m4.16xlarge","c4.large" , "c4.xlarge" ,"c4.2xlarge" , "c4.4xlarge","c4.8xlarge" , "c3.large" , "c3.xlarge", "c3.2xlarge", "c3.4xlarge" ,"c3.8xlarge"],
      "ConstraintDescription": "must be a valid EC2 instance type"
    },
    "StackID": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Description": "ID of the existing opsworks stack to edit"
    },
    "vpcId": {
      "Description": "VPC id of corresponding to the Environment",
      "Type": "String"
    },
    "subnetIds" :{
      "Description": "list of sunbnets in the chosen VPC",
      "Type": "List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>"
    },
    "ScriptSG":{
      "Description": "script security group",
      "Type" : "String"
    },
    "SG": {
      "Description": " layer security group",
      "Type": "String"
    }
  },
  "Resources":{
    "Layer": {
      "Type": "AWS::OpsWorks::Layer",
      "Properties": {
        "AutoAssignElasticIps" : false,
        "AutoAssignPublicIps" : true
      }
    },
    "SInstance1": {
      "Type": "AWS::OpsWorks::Instance",
      "Properties": {
        "Hostname": "S1",
        "AutoScalingType": "timer",
        "TimeBasedAutoScaling" : {
          "Friday"  : { "0" : "on",  "6" : "on", "12" : "on", "18" : "on" },
          "Monday"  : { "0" : "on",  "6" : "on", "12" : "on", "18" : "on" }
        },
        "RootDeviceType": "ebs",
        "StackId": {"Ref": "StackID"},
        "LayerIds": [{"Ref": "Layer"}],
        "InstanceType": {"Ref" : "InstanceType"}
      }
    },
    "Instance2": {
      "Type": "AWS::OpsWorks::Instance",
      "Properties": {
        "Hostname": "S2",
        "AutoScalingType": "timer",
        "TimeBasedAutoScaling" : {
          "Saturday": { "0" : "on",  "6" : "on", "12" : "on", "18" : "on" },
          "Sunday" :  { "0" : "on",  "6" : "on", "12" : "on", "18" : "on" },
          "Thursday": { "0" : "on",  "6" : "on", "12" : "on", "18" : "on" },
          "Tuesday" : { "0" : "on",  "6" : "on", "12" : "on", "18" : "on" },
          "Wednesday":{ "0" : "on",  "6" : "on", "12" : "on", "18" : "on" }
        },
        "RootDeviceType": "ebs",
        "StackId": {"Ref": "StackID"},
        "LayerIds": [{"Ref": "Layer"}],
        "InstanceType": {"Ref" : "InstanceType"}
      }
    },
    "ELB": {
      "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer",
      "Properties": {
        "ConnectionDrainingPolicy" : {
          "Enabled" : true,
          "Timeout" : 300
        },
        "ConnectionSettings" : {
          "IdleTimeout" : 60
        },
        "CrossZone" : true,
        "HealthCheck" : {
          "HealthyThreshold" : "3",
          "Interval" : "30",
          "Target" : "HTTP:80/ping",
          "Timeout" : "5",
          "UnhealthyThreshold" : "2"
        },
        "LoadBalancerName": "loadBalancer",
        "Listeners" : [{
          "InstancePort" : "80",
          "InstanceProtocol" : "HTTP",
          "LoadBalancerPort" : "80",
          "Protocol" : "HTTP"
        }],
        "Scheme" : "internal",
        "SecurityGroups" : [{ "Ref" : "ELBSecurityGroup" }],
        "Subnets" :  { "Ref" : "subnetIds"}
      }
    },
    "ELBAttach":{
      "Type": "AWS::OpsWorks::ElasticLoadBalancerAttachment",
      "Properties": {
        "ElasticLoadBalancerName" : {"Ref" : "ELB"},
        "LayerId" : {"Ref" : "Layer" }
      }
    }
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you will need to move them to the same region.

> Resources can be managed only in the region in which they are created. Resources that are created in one regional endpoint are not available, nor can they be cloned to, another regional endpoint.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#opsworks_region

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/08/aws-opsworks-adds-nine-regional-endpoints-and-asia-pacific-seoul-region-support/

Layer is missing the stackID parameter.

```
{
"Type": "AWS::OpsWorks::Layer",
"Properties": {
 "Attributes" : { String:String },
 "AutoAssignElasticIps" : Boolean,
 "AutoAssignPublicIps" : Boolean,
 "CustomInstanceProfileArn" : String,
 "CustomJson" : JSON object,
 "CustomRecipes" : Recipes,
 "CustomSecurityGroupIds" :  [ String, ... ],
 "EnableAutoHealing" : Boolean,
 "InstallUpdatesOnBoot" : Boolean,
 "LifecycleEventConfiguration" :                 LifeCycleEventConfiguration,
"LoadBasedAutoScaling" : LoadBasedAutoScaling,
"Name" : String,
"Packages" : [ String, ... ],
"Shortname" : String,
"StackId" : String,
"Type" : String,
"VolumeConfigurations" : [ VolumeConfiguration, ... ]
 }
  }
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-opsworks-layer.html

Comment: My default region is `eu-west-1` and cloudformation stack is in `eu-west-1` and same as the opsworks endpoint it is   `eu-west-1` . They are all in the same region but the cloudformation can't find the opsworks resources.

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake while copying the template to here. The layer does have the stackID as a parameter.

Comment: And the stackID is in the form "StackId": "aeb7523e-7c8b-49d4-b866-03aae9d4fbcb"

Comment: Yes exactly. I provided the right ID that we find in the page stack settings.

Comment: Did you try the ARN of the stack as well?

Comment: No it is not going to work any way because the parameter only takes the ID.

Comment: What's the output of "aws opsworks --region eu-west-1 describe-stacks" does it list the stack you are trying to change?

Comment: Yes It lists the stack